# onmouseover property doesn't working

Tags: php, javascript, html, onmouseover

I want to have a popup on mouseover... but it is not working.

In `Javascript` I am simply giving alert, the code works fine when I don't pass the parameters or send hard coded value but when I passed parameter using `php` tag it doesn't work.

```
<input type="hidden" name="val" value="<?php echo $values[0]; ?>" />

<div style=" padding:3px; border-top:solid 1px ;" id="<?php echo $values[0]; ?>" 
     class="display_box " onmouseover="he(<? print 't' ?>)"  align="left"
     onclick="document.getElementById('search_text').value='<?php print $values[0]; ?>';
document.getElementById('instant_display').style.visibility='hidden'">

<?php echo $values[0]; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: If your JavaScript doesn't work, then show us your HTML and JavaScript, not the PHP that generates it.

Comment: please edit your code...

Comment: use `echo` instead of `print`

Comment: he =function(ids)
{
 alert(ids);
}

Comment: I have Used even echo but the issue remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming my understanding of your question is correct, can you try doing it this way? **Note:** I have added a single quote before and after the PHP tag because your function seems to expect a string as input.

```
onmouseover="he('<?php echo 't' ?>')"
```